# mvn appfuse:full-source not working because of subversion

Tags: java, maven, svn

I am new for maven. I have appfuse maven project and it is embedded. I wanted to make it as full-source, but it gave me following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.appfuse.plugins:appfuse-maven-plugin:3.0.0:full-source (default-cli) on project OOS: svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/appfuse~svn/tags/APPFUSE_3.0.0/data/common/src'
```

I have searched solution for this and found [this](http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-appfuse-full-source-td3299734.html) information and applied that solution given in the site: adding

```
<trunk>https://svn.java.net/svn/appfuse~svn/</trunk>
```

inside of appfuse configuration tag. After adding this line to my pom.xml file, i have tried to run mvn appfuse:full-source, but it gave me the same error.

full stack is here:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycompany:OOS:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for org.springmodules:spring-modules-validation:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 363, column 33
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such    malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AppFuse Spring MVC Application 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appfuse-maven-plugin:3.0.0:full-source (default-cli) @ OOS ---
[INFO] [AppFuse] Installing source from data-common module...
[ERROR] 175002 : svn: PROPFIND request failed on   '/svn/appfuse~svn/tags/APPFUSE_3.0.0/data/common/src'
[ERROR] 175002 : svn: svn.java.net: Name or service not known
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.743s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 10 15:53:55 UZT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/144M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.appfuse.plugins:appfuse-maven-plugin:3.0.0:full-source (default-cli) on project OOS: svn: PROPFIND request failed on  '/svn/appfuse~svn/tags/APPFUSE_3.0.0/data/common/src'
[ERROR] svn: svn.java.net: Name or service not known
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the   following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have deleted whole repository directory in my .m2 folder, but did not help.

I wanted to check the link https://svn.java.net/svn/appfuse~svn/ but it asked username/password for entering. I think, this also can be a cause. I am using Ubuntu and tried to install subversion form Software center, but was no use: still the same problem.
I hope someone have faced this type of issue and will share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured it out. The problem was with mysql db. I was using default configurations in my project's pom.xml and by default it uses mysql dbms. It has connected with db and created all tables in mysql, but hasn't started the project. but, when i have changed db profile to postgresql, it has worked like a charm. I haven't understand why, but the appfuse maven project has some conflicts with mysql dbms.